# Как добавить еще один вариант сортировки для compareTo?

Tags: java, android, сортировка, arraylist

В MainActivity есть ArrayList

```
final ArrayList <ItemClass> nomenclatureList = new ArrayList<>()
```

Есть кастомный класс ItemClass с имплементацией Comparable **public class ItemClass implements Comparable**.

В это классе есть переменные, в частности

```
private String mNomenclatureName;
private String mNomenclatureWeight;
```

Тут же прописана возможность сортировки массива по одной из переменных

```
public int compareTo(ItemClass other) {
        return mNomenclatureName.compareTo(other.mNomenclatureName);
    }
```

Вызов сортировки производится по кнопке в классе с массивом, а именно:

```
Collections.sort(nomenclatureList);
```

Как добавить возможность сортировки и по **mNomenclatureWeight** ? Т.е. будет два выбора - сортировка либо по Name, либо по Weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте вдумаемся в проблему:

1. Есть некий массив объектов, который иногда надо сортировать по 1-му признаку, а иногда по другому признаку.
2. Соответственно компаратор должен знать по какому признаку ему сравнивать

Решение:

Оформляем метод:

```
public void setSortParameter(int what) {
    this.what=what;
}
```

Далее компаратор переписываем примерно так:

```
public int compareTo(ItemClass other) {
    if(this.what==0)
        return mNomenclatureName.compareTo(other.mNomenclatureName);
    else
        return mNomenclatureWeight.compareTo(other.mNomenclatureWeight);
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю, если честно, куда вставлять этот код. Куда не вставляю - всегда this.what=what подчеркивается...

Comment: Я может не так объяснил, но я хочу сделать 2 кнопки- первая будет сортировать по имени, вторая - по весу (и НЕ по имени).

Comment: Мда... Тяжелый случай, ладно будем считать, что я сам идиот и неверно все объяснил новичку :)